# Crawling the WP7 marketplace

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I've used code from this website:

http://www.manyniches.com/windows-phone/crawling-the-windows-phone-marketplace/

to crawl the Windows Phone marketplace. The good news is that it works and I can get all the info about any app in the marketplace...except the description.

Does anybody know how to modify the code to get the description for each app?

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with the description? I see that the blog post you're referring to has a description field for an app...

Comment: It's the short description and even that isn't pulled from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try using a program like [NotepadXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973) to analyze the following URL for Facebook app

http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/apps/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e/

you will notice that the tag for description is called 'Content'.

EDIT: Here is the code to retrieve the 'content' tag:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/apps/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e/");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var appDescription = doc.Descendants(ns + "content").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: The code on that website doesn't cater for Content - it doesn't return that data when I run the program.

Comment: not sure if it's case sensitive, but there's definitely a content tag there (right click -> view source)

Comment: I apologise, I was referring to the link I posted originally. I've tried retrieving the content tag from that website returns null...

Comment: I've found the tag in NotepadXML, it's called 'content' as expected but I don't know how to retrieve it. If it was a text tag like 'title' I could just copy the attached code but it happens to be an html tag. So, any ideas please :)?

Comment: @user1567095 I added the code to my answer which shows how to retrieve the content tag using that link example.

Comment: OK that's great, thank you! Do you have any idea how I could integrate it into the GetAppEntries method? When I pause the code and copy the xml into notepad, there is no description/content field.

Comment: well, as I don't see your exact code, it's hard to tell... perhaps you're using the wrong URL format, not similar to the one I mentioned in my answer? you need to have different URL formats for getting all apps, and then a different one for getting just one particular app.

Comment: The code I'm using came directly from the website in my original post. I have not modified this code, so if there's a problem, you might be able to identify it by looking at that code.